# Create Non-Collapsing navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do you go about making a `navbar` in Bootstrap that is non-collapsable and has a glyphicon button on the left without a `border`, text in the center and text on the right?

I know you can use `pull-left` and `pull-right` to move items to the left and to the right but when I try to add a glyphicon button to the navbar, it will become tiny and create a border around it.

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `pull-left-right`, use `text-left-center-right`. Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">insertnamehere's room</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">0 -1</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.pull-right {
  text-align:right;
}

.navbar { 
  padding: 10px;   
}
```

See [**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdBLqe).